# How do I figure out the error happening in the foreach loop?

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial to build a budget calculation using modules.For one of the function **calcTotal** in the module **budgetController** the guy uses the forEach method and I would like to rewrite it as a for loop.
In this function I am trying to calculate the total of all the expenses and income that the user input on the website. The value get passed to the data.object in the budgetController module. I insert different comments in the full code below to make it as easy as possible to understand.

```
    calcTotal = function(type){
    var sum = 0;

    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur){
    sum += cur.value;});

    data.totals[type] = sum;
    }

    var data = {
    allItems: {
    exp: [],
    inc: []
    },
    totals : {
    exp: 0,
    inc: 0 
    },
    budget: 0,
    percentage: -1
    };
```

The code above is working fine but I tried to do the same with for loop and for some reason is not working.

Could anyone rewrite the forEach method in the function calcTotal as a for loop so I can see what I am doing wrong? 
here is the full code:

```
var budgetController = (function(){

var Expense = function(id, description, value){
this.id = id;
this.description = description;
this.value = value;
};

var Income = function(id, description, value){
this.id = id;
this.description = description;
this.value = value;
};


calcTotal = function(type){
var sum = 0;

data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur){
sum += cur.value;});

data.totals[type] = sum;
}

var data = {
allItems: {
exp: [],
inc: []
},
totals : {
exp: 0,
inc: 0 
},
budget: 0,
percentage: -1
};

return{

addItem: function(type, des, val){
var newItem
var ID = 0;
if(data.allItems[type].length > 0 ){
ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id +1;
}
else{ID = 0};
//create new item based on exp or inc type
if (type === "exp"){
newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val)
}
else if(type === "inc"){
newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
}
//Push it into our data structure
data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
//returning the new element
return newItem;
},
calculateBudget: function(){
//calculate total income and expenses
calcTotal("exp");
calcTotal("inc");
// calculate the totalBudget
data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;
// calculate the pecentage;
data.percentage = Math.round((data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc) * 100);
},
testing: function(){
console.log(data);
},
getBudget: function(){

return{
budget: data.budget,
expenses: data.totals.exp,
income: data.totals.inc,
percentage: data.percentege

}
}

}

})()


var UIcontroller = (function(){

getDOM = {
inputValue: ".add__value",
inputDescription: ".add__description",
inputType: ".add__type",
addButton: ".add__btn",
expensesList: ".expenses__list",
incomeList: ".income__list"
};
return {
getInput: function(){

return{
value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(getDOM.inputValue).value),
description: document.querySelector(getDOM.inputDescription).value,
type: document.querySelector(getDOM.inputType).value,

};


},

getDomStrings: function(){
return getDOM;
},
displayListItem: function(type, obj){

var html, newHtml, element

if(type === "exp"){

element = getDOM.expensesList;

html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
}
else if(type === "inc"){

element = getDOM.incomeList;

html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="expense%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">10%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
}
newHtml = html.replace("%id%", obj.id);
newHtml = newHtml.replace("%description%", obj.description);
newHtml = newHtml.replace("%value%", obj.value)

document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newHtml);
},


clearFields :function(){
var fields, arrayField
fields = document.querySelectorAll(getDOM.inputValue +"," + getDOM.inputDescription);
arrayField = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

fields.forEach(function(current, index, array){
current.value = "";
});
arrayField[0].focus();
}



}
})()


var controller = (function(budgetCntrl, cntrlUI){
var updateBudget = function(){
var budget

// Calculate the Budget

var calcBudget = budgetCntrl.calculateBudget();
// Return the Budget
budget = budgetCntrl.getBudget();
console.log(budget);
//Display the Budget in UI
}


var addItem = function(){
var input, newItem, addItems, clearFields
// Get the file input data
input = cntrlUI.getInput();
// add new Item to the budget Controller
newItem;
if(input.description !=="" &&  !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0){    
newItem = budgetCntrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);
// display Items in the user interface
addItems = cntrlUI.displayListItem(input.type, newItem);
// clear Fields
clearFields = cntrlUI.clearFields();
updateBudget();

// calculate the budget
// display Budget in the user interface
}
}
var setupEventListener = function(){
var DOM = cntrlUI.getDomStrings();
document.querySelector(DOM.addButton).addEventListener("click", addItem);
}
return{
init: function(){
console.log("app has started");
setupEventListener();
}
}


})(budgetController, UIcontroller)

controller.init();
```

I hope I was clear.

Comment: You are getting the lenth of `allItems` from `data`... But There is no object initilized or passed called `data`... Can u explain? Share your console error

Comment: `data.allItems[type[i]] !== data.allItems[type][i]`.

Comment: "_is not working_" is not a problem description. What is it supposed to do? What is it actually doing? When you step through the code which exact step does something you don't expect?

Comment: As a sidenote, this looks like a task for [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) rather than a `for` loop.

Comment: According to the provided body of the `forEach` loop, `data.allItems.exp/inc` arrays contain objects which have `value` property. We've no clue what your object actually contains, and also what have you done to resolve the problem, and not even what the actual coding problem here is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
calcTotal = function(type){
var sum = 0;

data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur){
sum += cur.value;});

data.totals[type] = sum;
}
```

Could be re-written as:

```
function calcTotal(type){
   var sum = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < data.allItems[type].length; i++) {
     sum += data.allItems[type][i].value;
   }
   data.totals[type] = sum;
}
```

Full source: https://jsfiddle.net/gpj40raf/2/

However, may I give you some code review advice?

- `calcTotal` depends on data defined in the enclosing environment. This is not a good idea. It will be better to pass `data` as a parameter (in certain cases using the closure is good, but this is not one of them). One of the bugs that you have in the complete code is that `calcTotal` depends on values defined bellow. This will work because of JavaScript hoisting, but is not a good practice.
- Note that the `forEach` code depends that each value is in a `value` property, but the rest of the code is assuming that values are numbers (i.e. `calculateBudget`).
- The calculation of the total could be abstracted easily without depending on a particular `data` "shape". For example: `data.totals['type']=calcTotal(data.allItems['type'])`. This makes easy to understand what's going on.
- Take a look to Array functions `map`/`reduce`/`filter`. What they do is to abstract certain patterns in a way that's more declarative. For example, to sum values you can use: `values.reduce((total, value)=>total+value, 0)` (in one line you can express the same as `calcTotal`).
- Take a look to the ES6 constructs. All the new browsers support that today, and you'll be able to use `const`/`let`, string literals ,and `class` for `Expense` and `Income`.... the code will be shorter and easy to read.